# What other language has a similar syntax but different meaning between i++ and ++i

Tags: syntax

I know in programming language such as C# or C/C++

i++ will increment the value of i, but return the original value i while,
++i will increment the value of i, and then return the incremented value

In my interview, I have been asked question like 
"What other language has a similar syntax but different meaning between i++ and ++i?" and I don't know the answer.

Could someone knows the answer?

Comment: May I know the reason for down vote this question? Is that not clear enough?

Comment: The downvotes are probably for being off-topic for SO. This question has a lot of equally valid answers and isn't really related to a specific programming problem.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Haskell has a similar syntax but different meaning. In Haskell you might write:

```
prepend i = (i++)
append i  = (++i)
```

Which as you can see looks reminiscent of C/C++'s increment/decrement operators, but actually operates on lists. These are functions which take a list, and return functions which adds that list to either the beginning or the end of another list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope to get more useful answers regarding to this open question just like your answer. I just don't understand why people down vote this question.